# error while installing highcharts in angular app

Tags: angular, charts, highcharts, angular10, angular-highcharts

I want to install the highcharts package in angula pp but angular cli gives me error and like given below:

```
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@11.0.0-beta.33 requires a peer of @angular/cdk@^11.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@11.0.0-beta.33 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=11.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@11.0.0-beta.33 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=11.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@11.0.0-beta.33 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@>=11.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material-moment-adapter@11.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/material@11.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material-moment-adapter@11.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-validate-equal@1.0.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@^9.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-validate-equal@1.0.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@^9.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-validate-equal@1.0.4 requires a peer of tslib@^1.10.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path D:\FarooqDropbox\Dropbox\FarooqFolder\BugSmashClientApp\node_modules\highcharts
npm ERR! dest D:\FarooqDropbox\Dropbox\FarooqFolder\BugSmashClientApp\node_modules\.highcharts.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\FarooqDropbox\Dropbox\FarooqFolder\BugSmashClientApp\node_modules\highcharts' -> 'D:\FarooqDropbox\Dropbox\FarooqFolder\BugSmashClientApp\node_modules\.highcharts.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\biolab\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-08T13_43_50_089Z-debug.log
```

Please if some one knows tell me the solution of this problem.

Comment: If some one knows the solution then please tell me I am waiting for your responses.
Thanks

Comment: How did you try to do this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying but I am now able to solve this problem by uninstalling higher version packages and then again installing a lower version of packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this problem what I had done is that I simply go below file :

```
package.json
```

and write the package name which I want to install in my angular application and then the Visual Studio code automatically shows me errors and some suggestions to install this I just click these suggestions to install any package which I was not able to run using the command in ANGULAR CLI.